# Identification/Classification using BOW and SVM

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svm, emgucv, sift

I have been working on a project which would identify diseases from a leaf. I did search and worked out a few things. However some confusions remains.

I believe following should be the flow (suggestions required)

1. Crop diseased area (Manually) from leafs for building Vocabulary.
2. Use `SIFT` to get `keypoints` and `descriptors`
3. Create `Bag of Words` Vocabulary and `Cluster` (K means)
4. Train `SVM` from descriptors obtained above
5. To Evaluate/Classify Take input image of entire leaf and crop it to extract diseased area using `HarCascade`
6. Use `SIFT` to get `keypoints` and `Descriptors` and then use `SVM` to Predict.

Questions are

1. Is above workflow reasonable ? or i am missing something?
2. I am confused about how does SVM learns the Name of object or disease for example where does SVM get Name of object it learned or detected?
3. How does SVM outputs the Name of object it identified ?